# NumberFormatException: For input string: Select

Tags: java, sql, numberformatexception

I have a SQL query that does not work:

```
String name = comboBoxgetSelectedItem().toString(); //Getting name from ComboBox

String age = "select age from actress where name = '" +namn+ "'"; //Get age from previous name

int TheAge = Integer.parseInt(age); //Want the age to be stored as int
```

This gives the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "select age from actress where name = 'omg'"

"omg" is the name my Combox selects in the first code line.

Comment: did you execute you query before try to parse?

Comment: You are missing the "get stuff from the database" code

Comment: I got the "get stuff" further down in my forloop.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse the request instead of its result.

Comment: If "age" not is the result, whats the result?

Comment: age is only the request. You should execute it on a database to get the corresponding result. Please show the code where you execute the request.

Answer (score 0):

The NumberFormatException happens when trying to parse a non-numeric value. Try to debug the value of "age" and use try/catch blocks around the Integer.parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

I do really suggest you go and learn [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html) and then post your question, your query won't run magically on it's own. Or post a complete code instead of that misleading one.